# A solvable group of order $mn$ with $m,n>1$ and $(m,n)=1$, where $|H|=m, |K|=n$ for $H,K\le G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a solvable group of order $mn$, with $m,n>1$ and $(m,n)=1$. Let $H,K \leq G$ be such that $|H|=m$ and $|K|=n$. Show that one of the following items is valid: 
(i) The normal closure $H^G<G$ and $N_G(H)>H$; 
(ii) The normal closure $K^G<G$ and $N_G(K)>K$.

I showed that $G=H^GN_G(H)$ and $G=K^GN_G(K)$ using Hall's Theorem for solvable groups (existence and conjugation of Hall subgroups). If $H^G<G$, then $N_G(H)>H$, but if $H^G=G$, I am not able to show that item (ii) follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G$ is solvable, it has a normal subgroup $N$ such that $|G/N| = p$ is prime. Then $p$ must divide $m$ or $n$

If $p$ divides $n$ then $H \le N $, so $H^G \le N < G$.

Similarly, if $p$ divides $m$ then $K^G \le N < G$.

Comment: Why does $p$ divides $n$ imply that $H \leq N$?

Comment: Consider $HN/N$.

Comment: I was going to answer just that, if $H \nsubseteq N$, then $N<NH \leq G$, hence $G=NH$ since $|G/N|=p$. So $p=|G/N|=|NH/N|=|H/N \cap H|$ divides $|H|=m$, contradicting $(m,n)=1$.